# How can I change the color of all tables in word document?

Tags: ms-word

I wan't to change the color of all tables in a word document to white (backround and font). Futhermore I want black lines for all the rows and columns.

Is there a possibilty to change this for all tables at the same time?

I tried to select all tables at the same time but this doesn't work.

Comment: White background and font? What are you doing. This forum is for help with your existing code, not a code writing service. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Explore table styles.